# How to design a table for Role based Employee Attributes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I need a logic to design a table for the below concept

There are 3 roles in which each role performs specific values.

1.Trainee

2.Trainer

3.Supervisor

Employee will act in all the three roles.

Before Accessing the application the employee completes the registration process as we are providing separate link to the registration page  on each role.

1.Trainee Registration link

2.Trainer Registration link

3.Supervisor doesn't have link.The role is Applied to the trainer once the trainee selects him as a supervisor.

Once trainer is selected as a supervisor we populate supervisor dashboard page.

The logic which we need to cover is:

1.The Trainee Completes registration partially and the appropriate supervisor in which trainee selects will assign a trainer to provide trainings and completes trainee registration process.

2.The Trainer may act as a trainee in some occasions.He acts through by registering as a trainee.(The Registration is different for each role).

3.We need to maintain registration based on roles.

for eg:

if i am trainee when i move to trainer registration page i need to check whether he completes registration or not and if registered i need to populate information if not he will register again.

How to handle these logic ?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What exactly is the problem you are facing. Also, what version of sql server are you working with?

Comment: Following your logic a trainer can be a trainee at the same time or am I incorrect in this? 
You could just use employee as a table, then have intermediating tables that has a field trainer/trainee/supervisor that will hold a foreign key to the employee table, however I don't really see why you would want to remain registration based on roles, unless every registration would create a new field in the intermediating table rather than registering a new user

Comment: Yeah you are correct a trainer can be a trainee at the same time.

The Reason for separate link is ,the higher officials alone give links to register after consideration..@jeremy.C

Answer (score -1):

Create 3 Database Roles
Each role will have grant ( Select , Insert , Delete  , UPDATE ) for its relevant Table

Comment: Yes please, do provide the help you offer. Ideally by [edit]ing this post according to [answer]. Remember that this is not a blog, chat or forum, this is a Q/A collection. Answer are supposed to answer the question, not offer personal help services. (One exception, which however does not seem to apply here.)

Comment: I have removed the part which does not make an answer. If the part you offer to only provide on prompt is important, then you should add it to improve the perceived helpfulness of your answer.